# Access Denied for accessing amazon s3 - common data crawl

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, common-crawl

I am trying out a sample common data crawl example based on https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2015/03/analyzing-the-web-for-the-price-of-a-sandwich.html

I am running this below command in my local windows PC based on the instructions.

```
python mr_crawl_phonenumbers.py -r emr s3://aws-publicdatasets/common-crawl/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2014-52/wet.paths.gz s3://yelp/business_data.txt
```

But I am getting the below error.

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied –
```

Could someone help me with this.

Comment: Where did you put your AWS credentials?

Comment: Dummy check : did you open AWS account and deploy aws client as mentioned here : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html

Comment: @realharry I have done this as per the guide.

Comment: @mootmoot I have done this based on the guide.

Comment: It seems AWS change the bucket structure. The document you refer to is outdated. The common crawl bucket is call `s3://commoncrawl` now.  Try to use `aws s3 ls s3://commoncrawl`  to check it out. Ref : https://aws.amazon.com/public-datasets/common-crawl/

Comment: @mootmoot I tried this, not working.

Comment: How about `aws s3 ls s3://commoncrawl --region us-east-1` . In addition, you must have a valid AWS access key, you must go IAM to create one that assign with S3 access policy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159984/discussion-between-shamnad-p-s-and-mootmoot).